# How to update a single table using trigger in MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table PeroidicDeduction and the fields are ID(auto-increment),TotalDeduction(e.g.it can be loan),Paid(on which the deduction for each month),RemainingAmount,

What I want is when every time I insert or update the table---RemainingAmount will get the value of TotalDeduction-SUM(Paid)....and writ the following trigger...but dosen't work for me

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdatePD
ON PeroidicDedcution
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE

AS

BEGIN

UPDATE PeroidicDedcution
SET REmaininAmoubnt=(SELECT TotalDeduction-(SELECT SUM(Paid) FROM PeroidicDeduction) FROM                PeroidicDeduction)

END

NOTE: it is on a Single table

Comment: Do you mean single - within same table

Comment: yes i want to do the task with in a single table

Answer (score 2):

Create two triggers, an INSTEAD OF UPDATE and INSTEAD OF INSERT.  Here is the code for the INSTEAD OF UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdatePD ON PeroidicDedcution 
INSTEAD OF Update
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE p
    SET col1=i.col1
       ,col2=i.col2
    FROM INSERTED  i
        INNER JOIN PeroidicDedcution p ON i.PK=p.PK

UPDATE PeroidicDedcution 
    SET REmaininAmoubnt=(SELECT TotalDeduction-(SELECT SUM(Paid) FROM PeroidicDeduction) FROM PeroidicDeduction)
go
```

It will do both the original update that fires the trigger, as well as the SUM logic from the trigger in the question.

here is the INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.InsertPD ON PeroidicDedcution 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO PeroidicDedcution
    (col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT
       col1, col2, ...
    FROM INSERTED

UPDATE PeroidicDedcution 
    SET REmaininAmoubnt=(SELECT TotalDeduction-(SELECT SUM(Paid) FROM PeroidicDeduction) FROM PeroidicDeduction)
go
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a trigger to do this as it will recursively fire itself if you have an update trigger on a table and the trigger causes and update to the same table. rather add the logic to your insert and update stored procedures